# wordpress theme doesn't work on server

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

tried to develop a simple page using bootstrap, theme works fine on local server but when I upload it to my server seems it doesn’t get the included files. I am quite new in development part of this and don’t know if there is a certain path I should follow while uploading it.
Hi Chetan,

here is the link

http://halycon-studios.com/test/

and this is how it looks on my local server

http://halycon-studios.com/img.png
tnx,

poyraz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space (%20) in your CSS link.

I tested links with [W3C Link Checker](https://validator.w3.org/checklink?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhalycon-studios.com%2Ftest%2F&hide_type=all&recursive=on&depth=15&check=Check)

See: 
`Line: 16 http://halycon-studios.com/test/wp-content/themes/huber%20/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: Wow... thank you a lot i didn't see that coming :D I spent hours and I would spend even more... yet wouldn't be able to find the problem... What I don't get is how it worked on local... There was a space where you pointed, header.php in the line where I called bootstrap css

Comment: Glad I could help.Guessing that your local server ignored space in name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has problems loading resources (like Bootstrap).
On your local server, did you build the site on subdirectory too?
You might need to change the .htaccess file.

You can try with something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything. I am using wamp as a local server and i didn't understand what you mean by subdirectory, if what you mean I keep the files directly in root folder, then no, I have them in a separate folder. I packed the theme if you want to check out personally.

halycon-studios.com/huber.rar

Comment: Try this from the backend:
Go to "_Settings-> Permalinks_" and click "_Save Changes_" (no need to change anything).

Answer (score 0):

The link to your bootstrap CSS files is faulty. The link on your page is:

`http://halycon-studios.com/test/wp-content/themes/huber /css/bootstrap.css`

...which returns 404 not found. Note the space after 'huber', which is the problem.

The link you should be referencing is:

http://halycon-studios.com/test/wp-content/themes/huber/css/bootstrap.css

...which returns your bootstrap CSS.

You need to amend the funcion that enqueues your stylesheets. If you need more help with this, please amend your question to include your CSS enqueues. It should look something like this:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function my_add_styles() {

    // Set the proper path to your bootstrap CSS
    $path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/bootstrap.css'
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', $path );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_styles' );
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, space was the mistake. Works fine now, thank you.

Comment: What I still don't get is, how did work on local without problem even though there was a space...

Comment: Is the space there in your local dev environment?